# Same margin for book style

Tags: margins

How can I set the same margin on right and left side of the page?

I'm using \documentclass[12pt]{book}

but if i set

```
\evensidemargin 62pt
\oddsidemargin 62pt
```

I will have different margin for the two sides.

Comment: Please use `geometry` instead of setting the values directly. And this package has an `asymmetric` option, which does the job for you.

Comment: Add `oneside` as a class option.

Comment: I need two-side, but i want the the text will be at the same distance of each margin.

Comment: Then see @TeXnician's comment.

Comment: @NxA: I don't see a difference in the margin when using your setting. However, consider using `\usepackage[hmargin=62pt]{geometry}`.

Comment: With two-side printing, it goes against all the typographic rules, for obvious reasons…